# How to separate Arabic with alphabetical?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If you try this link https://jsfiddle.net/u4bxz74c/10/. Later the result will be like this

```
PART 1
<p id="posttextareadisplay">
    <p class="ENGLISH">This is a samplasde textssss</p>
    <p class="ENGLISH"><b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِن، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></p>
</p>

PART 2
<p id="posttextareadisplay">
    <p class="ENGLISH">This is a samplasde textssss <b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِن، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></p>
</p>
```

**Question PART 1** : If you see the code below, all `paragraphs` or `<p>` are `class="ENGLISH"`.

How to make it into a `paragraph` or `<p>` `class="ENGLISH"` to be `class="ARAB"`, if the writing in a paragraph is Arabic? But if the writing is not Arabic, so the paragraph of `class="ENGLISH"`

```
PART 1
<p id="posttextareadisplay">
    <p class="ENGLISH">This is a samplasde textssss</p>
    <p class="ENGLISH"><b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِن، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></p>
</p>

*****     I WANT TO BE LIKE THIS     *******
<p id="posttextareadisplay">
    <p class="ENGLISH">This is a samplasde textssss</p>
    <p class="ARAB"><b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِن، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></p>
</p>
```

**Question PART 2** : But if the Arabic joins with plain writing or regular fonts. So paragraph or `<p>` remain `class="ENGLISH"`

Like this

```
<p class="ENGLISH"> This is a sa <b>  لْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></p>
<p class="ENGLISH"><b>  لْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b> This is a sa</p>
<p class="ENGLISH"> This is a sa <b> ا لْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b> This is a sa</p>
<p class="ENGLISH"><b>  لْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b> This is a sa <b>  لْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></p>
```

---

**Note:** I've tried this code, but it seems, this code encapsulates the entire contents of the textarea

```
if (pattern.test(newText)) {
    str = newText.replace($format_search[i], $arab_format_replace[i]);
} else {
    str = newText.replace($format_search[i], $format_replace[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `RegExp` pattern from string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "` with `RegExp()` constructor with case insensitive flag `i`; iterate elements using a loop; if `.textContent` of element begins with one of the characters of string cast to `RegExp`  or every character of element `.textContent` is one of the characters within `RegExp`, set element `.className` to `"ENGLISH"`, else set element `.className` to `"ARAB"`.

Note that `id` of element in `document` should be unique. Also, `<p>` is not a valid child element of `<p>` element.

Substituted `class="posttextareadisplay"` for `id="posttextareadisplay"` at parent `<p>` element and `<span>` for child `<p>` element.

```js
const en = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ";

for (let el of document.querySelectorAll(".ENGLISH")) {
  if (new RegExp(`^[${en.slice(0, en.length -1)}]`, "i").test(el.textContent) 
     || [...el.textContent].every(char => 
          new RegExp(`${char}`, "i").test(en))) {
    el.className = "ENGLISH"
  } else {
    el.className = "ARAB"
  }
}
```

```html
PART 1
<p class="posttextareadisplay">
    <span class="ENGLISH">This is a samplasde textssss</span>
    <span class="ENGLISH"><b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِن، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></span>
</p>

PART 2
<p class="posttextareadisplay">
    <span class="ENGLISH">This is a samplasde textssss <b>فَإِذَا جَلَسْتَ فِي وَسَطِ الصلَاةِ فَاطْمَئِن، وَافْتَرِشْ فَخِذَكَ الْيُسْرَى ثُم تَشَهدْ</b></span>
</p>
```

Comment: If using your code, work but not yet typed anything. But if I try typing in textrea column. Thus, the Arabic returns to `ltr` https://jsfiddle.net/u4bxz74c/11/

Comment: Typing was not part of text of either question at OP.

Comment: Oh, I mean, what if to enter function on `function arabtanpaparaf(str)`